# Copying from s3 to EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services

I have java war file which is stored in s3 now I need to copy that file to the tomcat6 var/lib/webapps folder using ssh through my command line is it possible to do that. Or how do I send the war file my to remote instance tomcat6 folder. I failed to do that using scp.
scp -r localfile.txt username@192.168.0.1:/home/username/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the s3cmd command line tool to do just that.  Ensure you have s3cmd installed:

```
sudo apt-get install s3cmd
```

Then, from the command line, you can do lots of things (including downloading a file).

Run this to configure the tool for your S3 credentials:

```
s3cmd --configure
```

Then you simply run:

```
s3cmd get s3://<bucket name>/<file name> <local file name>
```

...to retrieve your file to the location of your choice.

Reference of all commands is here:

http://s3tools.org/s3cmd